# Sinc function derivative formula

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I was trying to find a formula for the derivative of the following function

$$
f_{\alpha}(x) = \frac{\sin(\alpha x)}{x}
$$

Since

$$
\sin^{(k)}(\alpha x) = \alpha^k g_k(\alpha x),
$$

where

$$
g_k(\alpha x) =
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
sin(\alpha x) & k \; mod \; 4 = 0 \\
cos(\alpha x) & k \; mod \; 4 = 1 \\
-sin(\alpha x) & k \; mod \; 4 = 2 \\
-cos(\alpha x) & k \; mod \; 4 = 3 
\end{array} ,
\right.
$$

and

$$
\left( \frac{1}{x} \right) ^{(k)} = (-1)^k \frac{k!}{x^{k+1}}
$$

by the Leibniz rule we have

$$
f_{\alpha}(x)^{(k)} = \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j} \sin^{(j)}(\alpha x) \left(\frac{1}{x} \right)^{(k-j)} = \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j} \alpha^j g_j(\alpha x) (-1)^{k-j} \frac{(k-j)!}{x^{k-j+1}}
$$

and assuming also I haven't done any mistake so far i have

$$
\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j} \alpha^j g_j(\alpha x) (-1)^{k-j} \frac{(k-j)!}{x^{k-j+1}} = (-1)^k \frac{k!}{x^{k+1}}\sum_{j=0}^k \frac{1}{j!} \alpha^j g_j(\alpha x) (-1)^{j} x^j
$$

which leads me at

$$
f^{(k)}_{\alpha}(x) = \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)^{(k)} \sum_{j=0}^k \frac{(-1)^{j}}{j!} (\alpha x)^j g_j(\alpha x)
$$

My question is, is there any mistake so far? If there's no mistake, is there a "simpler expression" than the one I'm proposing?

Comment: It is clear that $$g_k(x)=(\sin x)^{(k)}=\sin\biggl(x+\frac{k\pi}{2}\biggr).$$ See "Bai-Ni Guo and Feng Qi, On the Wallis formula, International Journal of Analysis and Applications, vol. 8 (2015), no. 1, 30--38".

Answer (score 2):

We may get rid of the $\alpha$ parameter by just noticing that $\alpha^{-1} f_{\alpha}(x)=\text{sinc}(\alpha x)$, hence the problem boils down to finding the derivatives of the $\text{sinc}$ function. The [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) of this function is a multiple of the indicator function of the interval $[-1,1]$, hence the derivatives of the $\text{sinc}$ function are given by fixed multiples of the inverse Fourier transforms of the function $g_k(t)=t^k$, supported on $[-1,1]$. The integrals
$$ \int_{-1}^{1} t^k e^{2\pi i m t}\,dt $$
are straightforward to compute through integration by parts. The derivatives can also be computed from the derivatives of $\frac{e^x}{x}$, since $\sin(x)$ is just the imaginary part of $e^{ix}$, and the formula:
$$ \frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left(\frac{e^x}{x}\right) = \frac{(-1)^n n! e^{x}}{x^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}x^k $$
is straightforward to prove by induction on $n$. Your expression is a simple by-product of it.

Comment: So is it correct or not? To me it looks similar to your second expression, which looks simpler than mine.

Comment: @user8469759: it is correct - you may take my last formula, replace $x$ by $\alpha ix$ and consider the real/imaginary part to recover your expression.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Jack, in the above comment you suggest replacing $x$ by $\alpha ix$ to get the derivatives of $\sin x/x$. I believe that it might be that one makes that replacement only for the $x$'s in the numerator. What do you think of that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This follows from directly applying the general formula
\begin{equation}\label{Sitnik-Bourbaki-reform}
\frac{\operatorname{d}^n}{\operatorname{d}x^n}\biggl[\frac{u(x)}{v(x)}\biggr]
=(-1)^n\frac{\bigl|W_{(n+1)\times(n+1)}(x)\bigr|}{v^{n+1}(x)}, \quad n\ge0
\end{equation}
for the ratio $\frac{u(x)}{v(x)}$ of two differentiable functions $u(x)$ and $v(x)\ne0$, where the matrix
\begin{equation*}
W_{(n+1)\times(n+1)}(x)=\begin{pmatrix}U_{(n+1)\times1}(x) & V_{(n+1)\times n}(x)\end{pmatrix}_{(n+1)\times(n+1)},
\end{equation*}
$U_{(n+1)\times1}(x)$ is an $(n+1)\times1$ matrix whose elements satisfy $u_{k,1}(x)=u^{(k-1)}(x)$ for $1\le k\le n+1$, $V_{(n+1)\times n}(x)$ is an $(n+1)\times n$ matrix whose elements meet $v_{\ell,j}(x)=\binom{\ell-1}{j-1}v^{(\ell-j)}(x)$ for $1\le \ell\le n+1$ and $1\le j\le n$, and $|W_{(n+1)\times(n+1)}(x)|$ is the determinant of the $(n+1)\times(n+1)$ matrix $W_{(n+1)\times(n+1)}(x)$. Concretely speaking, we have
\begin{align*}
\biggl(\frac{\sin x}{x}\biggr)^{(n)}
=\frac{(-1)^n}{x^{n+1}}
\begin{vmatrix}
\sin x & x & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dotsm & 0& 0 & 0\\
\cos x & 1 & x &0 & 0 & \dotsm& 0 & 0& 0\\
-\sin x & 0 & 2 & x & 0 & \dotsm& 0 & 0& 0\\
-\cos x & 0 & 0 & 3 & x & \dotsm& 0 & 0& 0\\
\dotsm & \dotsm & \dotsm & \dotsm & \dotsm & \ddots&\dotsm&\dotsm&\dotsm\\
\sin\bigl(x+\frac{(n-1)\pi}{2}\bigr) & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 & \dotsm& n-2& x & 0\\
\sin\bigl(x+\frac{(n-1)\pi}{2}\bigr) & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 & \dotsm& 0& n-1 & x\\
\sin\bigl(x+\frac{n\pi}{2}\bigr) & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 & \dotsm& 0& 0 & n
\end{vmatrix}.
\end{align*}

References

1. N. Bourbaki, *Elements of Mathematics: Functions of a Real Variable: Elementary Theory*, Translated from the 1976 French original by Philip Spain. Elements of Mathematics (Berlin). Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 2004; available online at http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-59315-4.
2. Feng Qi, Wen Wang, Bai-Ni Guo, and Dongkyu Lim, *Several explicit and recurrent formulas for determinants of tridiagonal matrices via generalized continued fractions*, Chapter 15 in: Zakia Hammouch, Hemen Dutta, Said Melliani, and Michael Ruzhansky (eds), *Nonlinear Analysis: Problems, Applications and Computational Methods*, SM2A 2019, pp. 233--248; Springer Book Series Lecture Notes in Networks and Systems, Volume 168, Springer, Cham, 2021; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-62299-2_15.
3. Feng Qi and Bai-Ni Guo, *Some determinantal expressions and recurrence relations of the Bernoulli polynomials*, Mathematics **4** (2016), no. 4, Article 65, 11 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.3390/math4040065.
4. Any paper at https://qifeng618.wordpress.com/2020/03/22/some-papers-authored-by-dr-prof-feng-qi-and-utilizing-a-general-derivative-formula-for-the-ratio-of-two-differentiable-functions.