# Recursive expression for the derivative for both $\frac{g(x)}{x}$ or for the specific case $\frac{sin(x)}{x}$

Tags: derivatives, recurrence-relations

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1855872/sinc-function-derivative-formula) I've derived a formula for the derivative of the sinc function. The formula was apparently correct, but I was wondering if there's a recurrence relationship between the derivative of order $k$ and, even all, the derivatives of order $0,1,...,k-1$, assuming now $f(x) = \frac{g(x)}{x}$

The attempt I did was exploiting this formula

$$
f(x) = \frac{g(x)}{x} \Rightarrow D^k f = \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}\frac{(-1)^{k-j}}{x^{k-j+1}} D^j g(x),
$$

Where $D^k = \frac{d^k}{dx^k}$. Then I've tried to substitute 
$$
xf(x) = g(x) \Rightarrow D^k (xf(x)) = D^{k-1}f + xD^{k}f
$$

But if I substitute in the previous summation I end up with nothing.. Do you think/know any reference for the specific case of the $sinc$ function instead?

Comment: The answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4660537 is perhaps useful for this question.